# Backup of a computer's whole network configuration

Tags: windows, backup, configuration

I'm now working on a system that runs on Windows 7 PCs, and makes heavy use of several Ethernet interfaces.

This system becoming complex, we now need a Backup \ Restore solution. One of the issues I encounter is on the network configuration.

It is necessary for us to be able to restore a backup on a PC from the same type (same make, same hardware configuration) that the source PC.
Network parameters we need to backup \ restore are, for each interface:

- IP Address (static)
- Subnet mask
- Interface Name (we can't assume at any moment that it has any recognizable value, like the default "Local Area Connection N")

---

First solution explored was using netsh naively.

```
netsh -c interface dump > netconfig.cnf
```

And then the following command to restore.

```
netsh -f netconfig.cnf
```

The main issue is that this solution doesn't restore interface names, and even worse, rely on interface names to restore other parameters.

---

Another possibility would have been that the PNPDeviceID or the InterfaceIndex of each interface would be unique and always distributed using the same sequence.
I had a look to those properties for all interfaces on a bunch of machine, and there was no apparent sequence.

---

How could I achieve such a Backup of a computer's network configuration in a reliable way?